# Prove that the Riemann zeta function is continuous on $(1, +\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, continuity

I've already proved that $\zeta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{s}}$ is uniformly convergent on $[1+\varepsilon, \infty )$ and not on  $(1,\infty  )$. Now, is there a link I can make to prove that it is continuous on $(1, +\infty)$ based on its convergence?

Comment: Hint: Continuous on a set is the same as continuous at every point of the set.

Comment: By a similar spirit as in GEdgar's comment, we have something called the [pasting lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pasting_Lemma).

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem do the trick?

Comment: Thank you all, I got it! :)